# Open ZipFile, Look for Specific File Type And Save File Name

Tags: excel, vba

So I posted a question here:

[VBA - Find Specific Sub Folders by Name Identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177263/vba-find-specific-sub-folders-by-name-identifiers)

This question was very broad, but I was facing specific issues I needed help identifying and resolving. Now, I managed to resolve those issues in the original post, however, there is still a good portion of the question unanswered and I would like to close the question only when I am able to post the full result.

Currently, what I still need to do, it the last 4 steps:

1. Open ZipFile
2. Look for .png extenstion
3. Grab the name of the .png file
4. Put the name in a cell in excel

The issue I am facing, is that of properly opening the zip file. I been through so many posts on this but NOTHING seems to work for me.

The closest I have come to accomplishing the task is what I found here:

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/109333-how-to-count-number-of-items-in-zip-file-with-vba-2007

I figure, if at the very least, I am able to enter the zip file, I can then work from there. But alas, I am still stuck at simply trying to open the file.

Here is the code I have (Using from the link above):

```
Sub CountZipContents()

    Dim zCount As Double, CountContents As Double
    Dim sh As Object, fld As Object, n As Object
    Dim FSO As Object

    CountContents = 0
    zCount = 0

    x = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Today\MyFolder\"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(x) Then

        For Each FileInFolder In FSO.GetFolder(x).Files

            If Right(FileInFolder.Name, 4) = ".png" Then

                CountContents = CountContents + 1

            ElseIf Right(FileInFolder.Name, 4) = ".Zip" Then

                Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                Set ZipFile = sh.Namespace(CVar(x & "\" & FileInFolder.Name))

                Debug.Print FileInFolder.Name

                For Each fileInZip In ZipFile.Items

                    If LCase(fileInZip) Like LCase("*.png") Then

                        CountContents = CountContents + 1

                    End If

                Next

            End If

        Next FileInFolder

    End If

    Set sh = Nothing

End Sub
```

The issue I get is on this line:

```
For Each fileInZip In ZipFile.Items
```

Error Message:

> Object variable or With block not set

Whenever I tried to use `Shell`, like below:

```
Dim oShell As New Shell
```

I get this error:

> User-defined type not defined

With the below:

Link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776890(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Dim oApp As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'get a shell object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

If oApp.Namespace(ZipFile).Items.count > 0 Then
```

I get this error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

On this line:

```
If oApp.Namespace(ZipFile).Items.count > 0 Then
```

References to links I have tried:

https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/tutorials/open-and-close-file-with-VBA-Shell/
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?38616-quot-shell-quot-not-work-in-Excel
[Excel VBA - read .txt from .zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757699/excel-vba-read-txt-from-zip-files)

I just don't understand why this step is taking so much time to complete.

Comment: For the first issue; I dont see that you defined what `FileInZip` is.  For the second issue you havent defined what `Shell` is.  VBA is looking for the object reference for both of those.

Comment: @ZackE Thank you for the reply. `FileInZip`, as my understanding goes, will simply be an element of what is in the `ZipFile`. Similar to how `FileInFolder` is not defined, but fills the gap of a file variable in the base folder.See this line `FileInFolder In FSO.GetFolder(x).Files`. The second issue with not having defined `Shell` is that 1) In every example I found, no one has "defined" `Shell`, they simply reference it like referencing any other data type. 2) If there is a reference to be added, I don't know about it and I cannot seem to find one either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is a really simple one: Your path `"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Today\MyFolder\"` contains already a trailing backslash, and when you set your `ZipFile`-variable, you are adding another one between path and filename. This will cause the `shell`-command to fail and `ZipFile` is `nothing`.

There are some minor problems with the code. I would recommend to use the `GetExtensionName` of your FileSystemObject to get the extension and convert this to lowercase so that you catch all files, no matter if they are `.PNG`, `.png` or `.Png`

```
   For Each FileInFolder In FSO.GetFolder(x).Files
        Dim fileExt As String
        fileExt = LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(FileInFolder.Name))

        If fileExt = "png" Then
            CountContents = CountContents + 1
            Debug.Print "unzipped " & FileInFolder.Name
        ElseIf fileExt = "zip" Then

            Dim ZipFileName As String, ZipFile, fileInZip
            Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            ZipFileName = x & FileInFolder.Name
            Set ZipFile = sh.Namespace(CVar(ZipFileName))

            For Each fileInZip In ZipFile.Items
                If LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(fileInZip)) = "png" Then
                    CountContents = CountContents + 1
                    Debug.Print "zipped in " & FileInFolder.Name & ": " & fileInZip
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next FileInFolder
```

Additionally the strong advice to use `Option Explicit` and define all your variables. And split commands into smaller pieces. This costs you only a few seconds of typing the extra lines but helps you when debugging your code:

```
' Instead of
' Set ZipFile = sh.Namespace(CVar(x & "\" & FileInFolder.Name)) 
' write
Dim fName as string
fName = x & "\" & FileInFolder.Name; ' Now you can check fName and see the problem.
Set ZipFile = sh.Namespace(CVar(fName))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Thank you for the advice as well, I was planning to go through the code later to fix it and make it more cleaner and efficient, but you have at least given some advice on where to get started. Thank you so so much, my brain is sore from trying to figure it out already. This works 100%!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

' Just to test CheckZipFolder
Sub TestZip()

    Dim sZipFold As String: sZipFold = "C:\Temp\MyZip.zip"      ' Change this to the path to your zip file
    CheckZipFolder sZipFold

End Sub


Sub CheckZipFolder(ByVal sZipFold As String)

    Dim oSh As New Shell        ' For this, you need to add reference to 'Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation'
    Dim oFi As Object

    ' Loop through all files in the folder
    For Each oFi In oSh.Namespace(sZipFold).Items

        ' Checking for file type (excel file in this case)
        If oFi.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Then
            MsgBox oFi.Name
            '..... Add your actions here
        End If

        ' This will make the UDF recursive. Remove this code if not needed
        If oFi.IsFolder Then
            CheckZipFolder oFi.Path
        End If
    Next

    ' Clear object
    Set oSh = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) First of all, THANK YOU SO MUCH for telling me which reference to use for `Shell`. Then secondly, I don't get any errors but with that said, the `If Statement` doesn't seem to find a match, even though there is a `.xls` file in the zip folder.